# adding field in multiple shapefiles and adding oid

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I am new to Python and programming in general. However, I was trying to find a solution to iterate on multiple (>700) shapefiles in one folder. Each shapefile needs a new field with an ID. 
I was able to insert the new field, but not perform the sequentially numbering.

I am working in the QGIS console (QGIS 2.2.0-Valmiera).

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
import glob


def fillfields(list, idx):
    i =0
    for item in list:
        new_values = {idx:item }
        provider.changeAttributeValues({i: new_values})
        i += 1


directory = r'D:\mypath'


files = glob.glob(directory+r'\*.shp')

for layer in files:
    layerLyr = QgsVectorLayer(layer,'test','ogr')
    layerLyr.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("oid", QVariant.Int) ] )
    layerLyr.commitChanges()

    provider = layerLyr.dataProvider()
    idx = layerLyr.fieldNameIndex('oid')
    n = layerLyr.featureCount()
    field1 = range(n)
    fillfields(field1, idx)
    layerLyr.updateFields()
```

Comment: It seems each time you call your `fillfields()` function, you are resetting `i` to 0. I would take these out the function and insert it back as a parameter. Also, could you update your QGIS to a more recent version (i.e. 2.18) as there have been major updates to the PyQGIS API within that time?